# Keyboard shortcut for hiding the dock?

Tags: inkscape

My dock looks like this (It contains the dialogs on the right of Inkscape):

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will show and hide it.  We have the dialog shortcuts here:

https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/keys.html

Also if we are only looking at a specific toolset dialog, like `Align and Distribute`.  How do we hide that dialog using the keys?

Comment: F12 toggles show/hide dialogs.  It's shown on the page you linked to. There's no shortcut for hiding individual dialogs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Dialog shortcuts

**Closing the dialog** (which is what the OP requested)

- `F12` toggle the dialogs dock
- *from within the dialog* you can close a specific dialog (for example the "Align" dialog) with `ctrl`+`W` or `ctrl`+`F4`

**Other useful shortcuts**:

- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`F`   Fill and Stroke
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`M`   Transform
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`W`   Swatches
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`T`   Text and Font
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`L`   Layers
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`A`   Align and Distribute
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`O`   Object Properties
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`H`   Undo History
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`X`   XML Editor
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`D`   Document Preferences
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`P`   Inkscape Preferences
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`E`   Export to PNG
- `Ctrl`+`F`   Find
- `Shift`+`Alt`+`B`   Trace Bitmap
- `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`7`   Path Effects